# Why some rule actions are disabled in google cloud armor?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

I'm trying to select "Rate based ban" rule action when creating a new policy but it's disabled and when I click on the option nothing happens.
I tried creating new rule (instead of default rule), targeting different backends, enabling Adaptive Protection but non off these helped
Also I'm using "Standard Tier" and have "Compute Load Balancer Admin" permission role as well

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

**EDITED:**

I tried cmd to create the policy but seems like "Rate based ban" is not available:

```
gcloud compute --project=[PROJECT_NAME] security-policies rules create 3 --action=rate-based-ban --security-policy=temp-policy --src-ip-ranges=\*
```

Gives Error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.security-policies.rules.create) argument --action: Invalid choice: 'rate-based-ban'.

Valid choices are [allow, deny-403, deny-404, deny-502, redirect-to-recaptcha].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Adaptive Protection you must enroll your account in Managed Protection Plus.

[Using Google Cloud Armor Managed Protection](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/managed-protection-using)

Right now some services/options are in beta/preview. Some customers can access these features and some cannot. If you have opted into Standard, then you can not access features enabled in Managed. If you have not opted into either (the time is ending soon) then you can access features not available in Standard. If you need clarification on your account status and which features you can access, contact Google Cloud Billing support (free) in the Google Cloud Console.

Given that Managed is not free, double-check what you have enrolled in. If you have not enrolled in either Standard or Managed, select one before you default to Standard, and the features you enabled stop working.

Comment: Actually you can use it without subscribing to the "Managed Protection Plus" (it's just an extra option to detect / alert for potential attacks) by opening the "Advanced configurations" and selecting "Enable" checkbox
My problem is i dunno why the other rule actions are disabled!

Comment: @RezaRajablou - The documentation states it is a feature of Managed Protection. For some customers, they can use the feature while it is in beta status. If you have already enrolled in **Standard Protection** then you must upgrade to **Managed Protection**. You might still be in the "not enrolled" beta phase.

Comment: You are right about **Adaptive Protection** only being available for subscribed customers but this doesn't answer my question that "Why some rule actions are disabled / not clickable?"
(actually i managed to select **Redirect(reCaptcha)** option through cmd command but i want to select "Rate based Ban" option)

Comment: 1/2) Right now some services/options are in beta/preview. Some customers can access these features and some cannot. If you have opted into Standard, then you can not access features enabled in Managed. If you have not opted into either (the time is ending soon) then you can access features not available in Standard. If you need clarification on your account status and which features you can access, contact Google Cloud Billing support (free) in the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: 2/2) Given that Managed is not free, double-check what you have enrolled in. If you have not enrolled in either Standard or Managed, select one before you default to Standard, and the features you enabled stop working.

Comment: yeah, i also got an answer in the google cloud slack community and seems like they're available in preview / beta (and only available to subscribed customers)
i dunno why they are showing those options in the UI though, please put your 1/2) and 2/2) comments in the answer so i can mark it as correct answer